# Why are the gpg commnd results for posted keys and fingerprints different from what I see in my terminal?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I enter: gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x4E2C6E8793298290
result: 
gpg: requesting key 93298290 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key 93298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) " imported
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   2  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2023-04-02
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)

I enter: gpg --fingerprint 0x4E2C6E8793298290

expected (from website):
pub   rsa4096/0x4E2C6E8793298290 2014-12-15 [C] [expires: 2020-08-24]
      Key fingerprint = EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
uid                   [ unknown] Tor Browser Developers (signing key) 
sub   rsa4096/0xD1483FA6C3C07136 2016-08-24 [S] [expires: 2018-08-24]
      Key fingerprint = A430 0A6B C93C 0877 A445  1486 D148 3FA6 C3C0 7136
sub   rsa4096/0xEB774491D9FF06E2 2018-05-26 [S] [expires: 2020-09-12]
      Key fingerprint = 1107 75B5 D101 FB36 BC6C  911B EB77 4491 D9FF 06E2

Actual:
pub   4096R/93298290 2014-12-15 [expires: 2020-08-24]
      Key fingerprint = EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
uid                  Tor Browser Developers (signing key) 
sub   4096R/D9FF06E2 2018-05-26 [expires: 2020-09-12]

Comment: gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --search 0xEB774491D9FF06E2